# Edit path of image file in Image viewer in C# / XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I am using below code :

```
String filepath = e.fullpath;
Image.source = new BitmapImage(new uri(filepath));
```

filepath output is:

```
file:///c://Folder//Location//Name.jpg
```

which is throwing error for Image.Source

required path format for Image :

```
c:/Folder/Location/name.jpg
```

Please Help,

Thank you in advance

Comment: @MongZhu I am using filewatcher which is retrieving the path.

Comment: `filepath=filepath.Replace("file:///","");`?

Comment: @Pikoh  No its not changing . I want to change "//" into "/".

Comment: I don't think having `//` instead of `/` is a problem when creating a new uri

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String filepath = e.fullpath;
Image.source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filepath).LocalPath);
```